# is defaultProps still needed in react 18 & Typecript

Tags: reactjs, react-18

```js
export function Modal({ open, body, header, onClose, loading }: Props) {
  return (
    ...
  )
    
}

Modal.defaultProps = {
  loading: false,
}
```

My understanding is that this is not needed and can be simplified like this

```js
 export function Modal({ open, body, header, onClose, loading = false }: Props) {
      return (
        ...
      )
        
    }
```

Comment: No, and you don't need typescript either. You can just specify the defaults in the argument.

Comment: Thank you. Trying to explain this to some people here :) they don't seem to understand